# How to differentiate between the usage of the words 'yobi'「曜日」and 'nichi'「日」?

Tags: translation, word-choice, jlpt

I know that yobi means 'day' of the week and 'nichi' means 'date'

I want to translate->

> What day is it tomorrow?

Which is the correct translation? ->

> 1. Ashita wa nan yobi desu ka?
> 2. Ashita wa nan nichi desu ka?

Can both the words be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking for the day of the week:

> 明日{あした}は何曜日{なんようび}ですか？
>
> What day (of the week) is it tomorrow?
>
> 明日は土曜日{どようび}です。
>
> Tomorrow is Saturday.

Asking for the date:

> 明日は何日{なんにち}ですか？
>
> What day (of the month) is it tomorrow?
>
> 明日は九日{ここのか}です。(九{きゅう} is nine but 九日 or 9日 has a special reading)
>
> Tomorrow is the ninth.

So both are valid depending on what exactly you're asking, but they *cannot* be used interchangeably.